# Kernel panic with new raw NVMe SSD plugged in 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel, ssd, nvme

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on my regular hard disk. Now, I have a new NAND NVMe SSD (Samsung 3.2TB) that I would like to migrate to. So I plugin my new SSD using PCIE NVMe adapter into PCIE slot in order to format and install new Ubuntu on it. But as soon as I plugin new SSD, and when I start my Ubuntu again from my normal hard drive, it does not start. I see some stack trace about kernel crash. My kernel version is 4.4.0-87-generic if that matters.

Any pointers on what might be going wrong. Let me know if I can provide more details.

Some hardware details:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Texas Instruments XIO2001 PCI Express-to-PCI Bridge
```

Comment: Is it detected in BIOS/UEFI? If so you may need to change some settings there (RAID > AHCI or explicitly set it as SSD, etc.). It may help if you [edit] and post other hardwares specs.

Comment: Visit the Samsung site and check for a firmware update for the SSD. Also check if there's one for the PCIe card. You might also try booting a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB 17.04 to see if it supports your hardware better. Report back.

Comment: Try using Ubuntu 17.04 since it has a newer kernel with support for more hardware (i had wifi problems on 16.04 and 17.04 fixed it)

Comment: @MichaelBay I don't think, I see it in the BIOS. I'll post more specs.

Comment: @heynnema My team has settled on 16.04 for build and dev environment so not  sure if upgrading will cause any issues but I'll look into it. How do I update the firmware for SSD?

Comment: Keep 16.04, but boot to a 17.04 Ubuntu Live DVD in `Try Ubuntu` mode. It won't bother your 16.04 installation at all. Go to the Samsung web site http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html and download Samsung Magician.

Comment: You have to use Enterprise version, as there is no consumer Linux version.

Comment: Can you post that kernel stack trace?